# Is true way use function for create instance and use it?

Tags: kotlin, coding-style, dry, solid

To Attention `DRY` principle, I want to know is true define a function to return instance of class or no!

You suppose we have a class and create instance many times in code, Is it better create instance it any time or define a function and use it?

```kotlin
class Job(name:String, maxPool:Int)
```

```kotlin
val job = Job("JOB_1",100)
val job2 = Job("JOB_2",100)
val job3 = Job("JOB_3",200)
```

or define a function

```kotlin
fun newJob(name:String = "NEW_JOB", maxPool:Int = 100) : Job{
   Job(name, maxPool)
}
```

```kotlin
val job = newJob()
val job2 = newJob("JOB_2")
val job3 = newJob("JOB_3")
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a [factory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).  And because it's closely coupled to the class, it's best to keep it in (or near) the class; that way it's easier to find, less likely to get out-of-date, etc.

- If the function isn't doing any significant processing before creating the instance, just call the constructor directly (as per your first example).
- Or if the function is merely inserting a constant value for some parameters, then give the constructor those [default argument](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#default-arguments) values.
- Or if the function is converting parameters to different types, or other simple processing, then use a [secondary constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#secondary-constructors) which does the conversion before calling the primary constructor.
- Or if the function is doing more complex processing, then put the [factory function](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/item-30-consider-factory-functions-instead-of-constructors-e1c747fc475) in the class's [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#companion-objects).  (If you call it [`operator fun invoke()`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#invoke-operator), then it will look like a constructor call — though it's only worth doing that if the parameter types make its meaning obvious; otherwise, [give it a meaningful name](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-style-guide/issues/22).)
- Only if the function is doing some processing that doesn't belong in the class at all — e.g. it's implementing some business logic that the class doesn't need to know about — is it worth having a separate factory function as in your second example.